# Connecting to access controlled MongoDB replicaSet from Python Eve

Tags: mongodb, eve

I have an Eve application that I want to connect to a mongodb replicaset. I was able to do thisby setting the `MONGO_URI` parameter in `settings.py` to `mongodb://host/dbName?replicaSet=replicaSetname`
however, now that I have enabled access control on the replica set, I can't seem to pass the user credentials in.

I am using a uri of the form:

`mongodb://user:password@host/dbName?replicaSet=replicaSetName&authSource=admin`

Most infuriatingly of all, when I serve this URI directly to the database, it connects and logs in without issue. But if I try to access something through eve I get the following error:

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.`

I have tried several variations, including settings the `MONGO_USERNAME` and `MONGO_PASSWORD` parameters in eve. The only possible issue I can think of is that the user I created for eve has limited permissions (readWrite on one database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much effort I managed to figure out how to do it on eve, it involved a few settings that were not mentioned in the eve documentation:

```
MONGO_HOST = 'mypod-1.mongo,mypod-2.mongo,mypod-3.mongo;
MONGO_USERNAME = 'user'
MONGO_PASSWORD = 'pass'
MONGO_DBNAME = 'mydb'
MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE = 'admin'
MONGO_REPLICA_SET = 'mySet'
```

And also, because this tripped me up, don't have `MONGO_URI` set to anything in your settings, not even `None`, as eve will attempt to use the URI over *any* other setting if it finds that variable declared.

Comment: Good job. I will look into the codebase, or the documentation at the very least, to see if we can address this in the framework itself.